# pdfbox Font TrueType cause stripper.getText() error

Tags: apache, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I have some pdf need to extract to text
only one pdf is truetype
and it cause following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getAdvanceWidth(I)I
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.getFontWidth(PDTrueTypeFont.java:677)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.getFontWidth(PDSimpleFont.java:231)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:411)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowText.process(ShowText.java:45)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:557)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:460)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:385)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:344)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:257)
```

I check the api source code and still can't get through it.
Is there something I can do?
or the 2.0 version solve this problem.

Comment: Are the versions of your fontbox and pdfbox jars identical? `NoSuchMethodError` situations usually would have been caught at build-time.

Comment: oops, indeed. I've now deleted my own answer.  Btw, thanks for all the good answers here. I've upvoted many of them :-)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr *thanks for all the good answers here* - Actually I used those questions to dive into PDFBox and learn a bit about it myself :). *upvoted many of them* - Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's really stupid mistake I made, I check the build path again. Found mutiple version of font jar in there. Thanks @mkl a lot!

Comment: Glad that you found it! Please answer your own question (so that it helps other people in the future), or delete the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an big issue but some tiny mistake

Thanks to mkl and Tilman Hausherr

It's only **buildpath problem**.

First , I have muti versions of fontbox that I didn't aware of.

Just check it again and check it hard !

If others have same error, check the dependencies

```
pdfbox-1.x.x.jar
fontbox-1.x.x.jar
```

**they need to be the same!**

Comment: Please be more detailed, e.g. add some text like "I had several versions in the build path". I know from experience that it is these tiny mistakes that can cost hours of work :-(